# Identity Api in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET. I am trying to implement role based security in ASP.Net web forms. I have searched google but couldn't find any good explanation on implementing asp.net Identity Control. All of the tutorials was based on MVC but i don't want to go with MVC.

Can anyone guide me or share a source where implementing Identity web api in web forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think this site may be helpful to you as you needed .
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security